# Spring MVC - Autowired field from header

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, autowired

I made web service with spring mvc(version 4).
This service used token in http header for authorization.
I want to value in http header bind to field in model class auto.
Is it possible? How can I do?
(See below code and comment)

## Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/order")
public class OrderController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderController.class);

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Order> getAll() throws Exception {
        // I want to remove two line below with auto binding (userToken field in model)
        //   in all controller using token value  
        String token = request.getHeader("X-Auth-Token"); // remove~
        orderService.setUserToken(token); // remove~

        orderService.getAllbyUser()

        return items;
    }
}
```

## Model(Service)

```java
@Service
public class OrderService {
    //@Autowired - is it possible?
    private String userToken;

    public String setUserToken(String userToken)
    {
        this.userToken = userToken;
    }

    public List<Order> getAllbyUser() {
        String userId = userMapper.getUserId(userToken);
        List<Order> list = orderMapper.getAllbyUser(userId);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your OrderService as illustrated here is a singleton so I think setting the userToken value here is not something you intend, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Autowire is for Spring to inject beans one to another. If you want to inject a String to a bean you can with the org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value annotation.

For example:

```
@Value("${user.token}")
private String userToken;
```

This will make Spring search of the `user.token` in the VM args and other places (which I don't remember and in some specific order).

But again, as said in my initial comment, from the code you show here it seems to be an error setting this field as it is context specific and the @Service (by default) indicates that the OrderService is a singleton.

Comment: Token value come from client(http header). It's different each by user.

Comment: Exactly, so this is why you don't want to set it in the @Service state cause it will be visible for all. Consider the case where you are dealing with concurrent users that are calling your API at the same time. There will be a race and the output will not always be what you intended

Comment: Ok. This is impossible. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a header value from request, you can use `@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token")` in your controller, as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public List<Order> getAll(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") String token) throws Exception {
    orderService.setUserToken(token); // remove~
    orderService.getAllbyUser()
    return items;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Token is frequently used in Services. All services call setUserTaken method before use. So I want to remove repeat coding.

Comment: You may create a base controller for each of the controllers or implement an request interceptor.